# RabbitMQ — Why are my Routing Keys being ignored when using topic exchange

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp

I'm using RabbitMQ to coordinate events between a collection of services as follows:

### User Manager

- emits `user.collect` when it wants user data to be collected from a separate service
- listens for `user.collected` which is emitted by a separate service

### User Collector

- listens for `user.collect` when it is supposed to collect some user data, and
- emits `user.collected` when it's collected the data.

There are also other services that listen for events like

- `user.created`,
- `user.updated`,
- `user.deleted`

In addition there are services that listen for more general events like

- `#.created`
- `user.#`

and so on.

So I am using a `topic` exchange.

### My setup is as follows

```
| exchange | type  | queue           | routingKey     |
| -------- | ----- | --------------- | -------------- |
| MY_APP   | topic | USER_COLLECTION | user.collect   |
| MY_APP   | topic | USER_COLLECTION | user.collected |
```

All of the services talk to the exchange called `MY_APP`.

The User Manager creates a producer that emits the `user.collect` event to the `MY_APP` exchange with `routingKey` `user.collect`, and it creates a consumer that listens on the queue `USER_COLLECTION` for events with routingKey `user.collected`.

The User Collector creates a producer that emits the `user.collected` event to the `MY_APP` exchange with routingKey `user.collected` and it creates a consumer that listens on the queue `USER_COLLECTION` for events with routingKey `user.collect`.

However I'm finding that the User Manager emits `user.collect` and this is picked up by the User Manager itself with the listener for `user.collected`.

It's as if the routingKey is being ignored. What am I doing wrong?

#### Update

See [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52942842/rabbitmq-why-does-the-wrong-subscriber-get-a-published-message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create different queues for each Consumer and bind queue(s) to topic exchange using appropriate binding key user.collect or user.collected.

1. Queue delivery message to one of it's consumer, not to all of it's consumers.
2. Messages are routed to Queue(s) based on it's binding key to Topc Exchanges.

Check this link for more detailed examples. https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html

Comment: Thanks.  So I have tried that and am still finding that the service listening for one queue is picking up messages for the other queue.  I have detailed this in a follow-up question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52942842/rabbitmq-why-does-the-wrong-subscriber-get-a-published-message