# RabbitMQ — Why does the wrong subscriber get a published message?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp

I have two services, **Manager** and **Collector**.

1. **Manager** is subscribed to Queue `COLLECTED_USER` with routingKey `user.collected` and invokes a `UserCollected` handler.
2. **Collector** is subscribed to Queue `COLLECT_USER` with routingKey `user.collect` and invokes a `CollectUser` handler.

There can be multiple collectors so I have set `exclusive` to `false` (see below for code).

There are also other services that listen for events like

- `user.created`,
- `user.updated`,
- `user.deleted`

In addition there are services that listen for more general events like

- `#.created`
- `user.#`

and so on.

So I am using a `topic` exchange.

### Setup

```
| exchange | type  | routingKey     | queueName      |
| -------- | ----- | -------------- | -------------  |
| MY_APP   | topic | user.collect   | COLLECT_USER   |
| MY_APP   | topic | user.collected | COLLECTED_USER |
```

### What should happen:

1. **Manager** publishes message with routingKey `user.collect`
2. **Collector** gets the `user.collect` message and invokes a `CollectUser` handler
3. **Collector's** `CollectUser` handler does work, then publishes a message with routingKey `user.collected`
4. **Manager** gets the `user.collected` message and invokes the `UserCollected` handler

### What actually happens:

1. **Manager** publishes message with routingKey `user.collect` (correct)
2. **Collector** gets the `user.collect` message and invokes a `CollectUser` handler (correct)
3. **Manager** also gets the `user.collect` message and invokes the `UserCollected` handler with the wrong data. (wrong)
4. **Collector's** `CollectUser` handler does work, then publishes a message with routingKey `user.collected` (correct)
5. **Manager** gets the `user.collected` message and invokes the `UserCollected` handler (correct)

### My Question

Why does the **Manager** get the `user.collect` message, given:

1. It's listening on the `COLLECTED_USER` queue not the `COLLECT_USER` queue, and
2. The **Collector**, which is listening on the `COLLECT_USER` queue, has already handled the message.

### Implementation details

I create the subscribers and publishers as follows (trimmed for relevance)

#### Creating a Subscriber

given the AMQP `url` and params `url`, `exchange`, `type`, `routingKey`, `queueName` and `handler`

```
const connection = await amqp.connect(url)
const channel = await connection.createChannel()
channel.assertExchange(exchange, type, { durable: true })
const result = await channel.assertQueue(queueName, { exclusive: false })
channel.bindQueue(result.queue, exchange, routingKey)
channel.prefetch(1)
channel.consume(result.queue, handler)
```

#### Creating a Publisher

given the AMQP `url` and params `url`, `exchange`, and `type`

```
const connection = await amqp.connect(url)
const channel = await connection.createChannel()
await channel.assertExchange(exchange, type, { durable: true })
```

#### Publishing

given the `channel` and params `exchange`, `routingKey`, and `message`

```
await channel.publish(exchange, routingKey, message)
```

### Note

This question is a follow-on from [RabbitMQ — Why are my Routing Keys being ignored when using topic exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52928669/rabbitmq-why-are-my-routing-keys-being-ignored-when-using-topic-exchange)
.

Comment: This should work as you described. At this point sharing a complete, working set of code that reproduces this issue is the best way to get assistance. The output of `rabbitmqctl list_exchanges name type internal arguments policy` and `rabbitmqctl list_bindings source_name source_kind destination_name destination_kind routing_key arguments` would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally worked out what my problem was.  A dirty exchange.  While experimenting with this I'd inadvertently added an exchange that was routing messages to the wrong queue, and this was causing my confusion.

To fix it I fired up the RabbitMQ admin GUI and deleted all of the queues and let my code create the ones it needed. There was no issue with the code as outlined above.